# can I use microsoft code ide for F# without visual studio?

Tags: f#

I want to wait until VS2015 releases rather than install VS2013 only to turn around and worry about interactions between VS2013 and VS2015 when it releases ( or any beta/RC).

In the mean time can I either run `.fsx` scripts or `F#` of any sort in [MS Code IDE](https://code.visualstudio.com/) in windows without installing visual studio?

Comment: Have a look at the F# plugin for Atom: https://github.com/fsprojects/atom-fsharp. Visual Studio Code is pretty much a clone of Atom, so it's very similar. And the F# plugin for Atom gives you most of the stuff from full Visual Studio.

Comment: I've just been trying this suave example on vs code from Claus Sørensen: http://blog.geist.no/suave-io-introduction-and-example-part-2-setting-up-a-project/ - no repl in vs code (I think) but with a web project the dev process is fairly interactive anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Fsharp is not a scripting language. If you use MS Code, you need to invoke the compiler manually, or find out if you can configure MS code to do it for you. 
If you just want to learn the language without commiting to an IDE, check out online editor (I like this one http://www.compileonline.com/compile_fsharp_online.php)

You won't have any issues going from VS2013 to VS2015, they will be backwards compatible. However, the new .net is going to have some major changes to its core libraries. You may want to read up about it (https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/news/vs2015-vs.aspx#Net)

Comment: Visual Studio Code is able to compile C# code. It would be a shame if there was no way to configure it to compile F# code, since the capability to run compilers (at least the C# and TypeScript compilers) is clearly built in. Maybe when they add the promised extensions mechanism...